# Regex.CompileToAssembly how to set .dll file location

Tags: .net, regex, f#

I'm experimenting with precompile regexes in an .fsx script. But I can't figure out how to specify the .dll file location for the generated assembly. I've tried setting properties such as `CodeBase` on the `AssemblyName` instance used by `Regex.CompileToAssembly` but to no avail. Here's what I have:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let rcis = [|
    new RegexCompilationInfo(
        @"^NumericLiteral([QRZING])$",
        RegexOptions.None,
        "NumericLiteral",
        "Swensen.Unquote.Regex",
        true
    );
|]

let an = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("Unquote.Regex");
an.CodeBase <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__  + "\\" + "Unquote.Regex.dll"
Regex.CompileToAssembly(rcis, an)
```

I'm executing this in FSI and when I evaluate `an` I see:

```
> an;;
val it : System.Reflection.AssemblyName =
  Unquote.Regex
    {CodeBase = "C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Unquote\code\Unquote\Unquote.Regex.dll";
     CultureInfo = null;
     EscapedCodeBase = "C:%5CUsers%5CStephen%5CDocuments%5CVisual%20Studio%202010%5CProjects%5CUnquote%5Ccode%5CUnquote%5CUnquote.Regex.dll";
     Flags = None;
     FullName = "Unquote.Regex";
     HashAlgorithm = None;
     KeyPair = null;
     Name = "Unquote.Regex";
     ProcessorArchitecture = None;
     Version = null;
     VersionCompatibility = SameMachine;}
```

But, again, I don't see *C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Unquote\code\Unquote\Unquote.Regex.dll* like I want. If I search my C-drive for *Unquote.Regex.dll*, I do find it in some temp AppData folder.

So, how can I correctly specify the .dll file location for an assembly generated by `Regex.CompileToAssembly`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that CompileToAssembly doesn't respect CodeBase or any other property in AssemblyName and instead just saves result assembly to the current directory. Try to set System.Environment.CurrentDirectory to the proper location and revert it back after saving.

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

type Regex with
    static member CompileToAssembly(rcis, an, targetFolder) = 
        let current = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
        System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <- targetFolder
        try
            Regex.CompileToAssembly(rcis, an)
        finally
            System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <- current


let rcis = [|
    new RegexCompilationInfo(
        @"^NumericLiteral([QRZING])$",
        RegexOptions.None,
        "NumericLiteral",
        "Swensen.Unquote.Regex",
        true
    );
|]

let an = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("Unquote.Regex");
Regex.CompileToAssembly(rcis, an, __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__)
```